# issue on: Unhandled Exception: [firebase storage/unauthenticated] User is unauthenticated. Authenticate and try again

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, mobile, firebase-storage

I have to upload pictures to the firebase storage. I tried to remedy the problem with 2 different methods to no avail.

The first one: it says that I am unauthenticated like in the title of the topic. So I looked on the internet and I found the following [link](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firebase-app-check-a-new-dimension-in-app-security-96c807978ae).

The fact is that there is no tutorials on the App Check. I don't know if I have to use it or if I can do something else.

On some [topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/safetynet-provider?authuser=0#kotlin%20ktx_1) they recommend to implement some lines of code but I don't know in what file.

thank you for your help

[here are the firebase rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y1bU.png)

Comment: show your firebase storage security rules

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.